# How to handle jQuery UI accordion with Smallipop plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to implement the Smallipop plugin with the jQuery ui Accordion menu.

Accordion menus are loading in the div which contain the content but on hover element for tool tip its not getting the Accordion menus in the tool tip , can anyone tell why is not accordion not loading in tooltip ?

Comment: have a code sample or anything? what have you tried? what value is the smallipop adding that jquery tool tip doesnt offer, i think they play better together

Comment: Include the code into your question

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mrshahrukh123/q0z12eo6/ fiddle here